# How to center vertically small (tiny) equation numbered tags?

Tags: equations, formatting, vertical-alignment, tags

The following MWE procudes this result:

[image: eq]

As you see, I want to have tiny equation numbers/tags, but currently it is not centered vertically of course (as the rule shows), it lies on the baseline. How can I possibly change this? That is, I want to print (1) a bit higher.

(NB: I do *not* want to change the formatting of `\ref, \eqref, \cref` though).

Thanks for your ideas!

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtagform{myTag}{%
    \fontsize{5}{0}\sffamily\selectfont\color{green}(}{)}
\usetagform{myTag}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\eqref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{%
    \textup{(\ref{#1}})
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test :
\begin{equation}\label{fun_eq}
x^2+y^2+z^2 + x^2+y^2+z^2 + x^2+y^2+z^2 =
3(x^2+y^2+z^2)
\mathllap{\rule[2.6pt]{12cm}{0.2pt}\hspace{-1.5cm}}
\end{equation}
My favorite equation is \ref{fun_eq}, \eqref{fun_eq}, \cref{fun_eq}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TeX primitive `\vcenter` centers boxes vertically around the math axis (corresponding to the line you have drawn with a bit of trial/error, I presume) without having to guess the right amount.

Since the parentheses have a larger height and a depth than the numbers, the concept of vertical centering is relative: should the whole tag (including parentheses) be vertically centered, or only the number? I show both possibilities; I have also fixed your redefinition of `\eqref` a bit. (I've changed the color to make the screenshot clearer; green on white is difficult to read.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn for smaller snapshot
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtagform{myTagA}% vertically centered on parentheses
   {%
    $\vcenter\bgroup
    \hbox\bgroup\bgroup % double group to avoid color leaking
    \fontsize{5}{0}\sffamily\selectfont\color{blue}%
    (%
   }{%
    )%
    \egroup\egroup
    \egroup$%
   }

\newtagform{myTagB}% vertically centered on number
   {%
    $\vcenter\bgroup
    \hbox\bgroup\bgroup % double group to avoid color leaking
    \fontsize{5}{0}\sffamily\selectfont\color{blue}%
    \smash{(}%
   }{%
    \smash{)}%
    \egroup\egroup
    \egroup$%
   }

\renewcommand*{\eqref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{%
    \textup{(\ref*{#1}})%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

test : \usetagform{myTagA}
\begin{equation}\label{fun_eq}
\mathrlap{\rule[2.6pt]{5cm}{0.2pt}}
a + b = c
\end{equation}
My favorite equation is \ref{fun_eq}, \eqref{fun_eq}, \cref{fun_eq}
test : \usetagform{myTagB}
\begin{equation}
\mathrlap{\rule[2.6pt]{5cm}{0.2pt}}
a + b = c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here a closer snapshot of the equation numbers:

[image]

Comment: OK, I see, I should have used something like `\mathrlap{\vcenter{ \rule{12cm}{0.2pt}  }} ` ;-).   Thanks!

Comment: @Watson Not quite. `\vcenter` expects vertical material but `\rule` is a LaTeX macro which expands to a rule in *horizontal* mode, so the result wouldn't be correct. You need `\mathrlap{\vcenter{\hrule width 12cm}}`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain to me these things! So `hrule` is used in "vertical mode"? (I think the "h" in "hrule" is just reminds us that `hrule` prints a horizontal line, which has apparently nothing to do with _horizontal mode_).

Comment: @Watson Yes, that's a very strange thing in TeX: `\hrule` is a vertical mode comand, and `\vrule` works in horizontal mode. The idea is that if you do `\vbox{\hrule\hbox{...}}` then the `\hrule` will automatically stretch to the natural width of the `\vbox` if no explicit parameters are given. Of course, if you declare a larger height than with the rule will look like a vertical one, but in TeX's eyes that's irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I have still a lot to learn in (La)TeX!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `environ`:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{LiftBox}{\raisebox{.3em}{\BODY}}

\newtagform{myTag}{%
    \fontsize{5}{0}\sffamily\selectfont\color{green}\begin{LiftBox}(}{)\end{LiftBox}}
\usetagform{myTag}
```

[image]

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{LiftBox}{\raisebox{.3em}{\BODY}}

\newtagform{myTag}{%
    \fontsize{5}{0}\sffamily\selectfont\color{green}\begin{LiftBox}(}{)\end{LiftBox}}
\usetagform{myTag}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\eqref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{%
    \textup{(\ref{#1}})
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test :
\begin{equation}\label{fun_eq}
x^2+y^2+z^2 + x^2+y^2+z^2 + x^2+y^2+z^2 =
3(x^2+y^2+z^2)
\mathllap{\rule[2.6pt]{12cm}{0.2pt}\hspace{-1.5cm}}
\end{equation}
My favorite equation is \ref{fun_eq}, \eqref{fun_eq}, \cref{fun_eq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! There is some manual adjustment, but at least this solution is easy to understand! Thanks :-)