# How to vertically align equation tags?

Tags: equations, alignment, tags

Consider the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter  % make "@" a letter-like symbol
\renewcommand{\tagform@}[1]{\maketag@@@{\color{gray!120}\tiny(#1)\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother  % revert "@" back to other

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How can I vertically align the equation's tag? That is, instead of

[image]

I want

[image]

where I used the red box to sketch the alignment. Any ideas?

As a side note, is there any particular motivation for picking either alignment style?

**Edit:** I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586933/how-to-center-vertically-small-tiny-equation-numbered-tags), but it does not answer my question, as I am looking for a straightforward way to adapt my code, possibly with `\vcenter`.

Comment: I don't really see the issue here. `x` and `(1)` have the same base line. So what exactly are you vertically centering in relation to?

Comment: @daleif -- I think the request is for alignment along the common math axis, which would imply a higher baseline for a `\tiny` equation number.